# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, dns, web-config, plesk

i think i  have a problem with the config file , Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication
the code in the localhost is working with no errors
but in the browser its gives me error
not that i already check IIS manager and the application pool .net version 4

this is the code in the config file

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET 
  application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.7.2>
    tempDirectory="G:\PleskVhosts\****.com\tmp" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
    </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" 
    value="None" >
    </add>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>

      <add name="conn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
      connectionString="Data Source=******;Initial 
      Catalog=***;Integrated 
      Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
     
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" 
       <publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" 
      newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" 
      publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" 
       newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
     </configuration>
```

this is the error i got

> login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1524
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +467
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +1145
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +111
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1567
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   cosys.login.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Green Metal\source\repos\cosys\cosys\login.aspx.cs:29
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11596744
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +274
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1890
```

Comment: @yacc i did that thx , i think i have a problem with the connection to database

Comment: @yacc sorry for the confusion , yes  , i remove the compiler from the config file , so the 'Unrecognized attribute targetFramework' error disappear, and my log in page is working , but when i try to log in ,, this error appears (Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.) can u help plz

Comment: Could you add a sentence about your setup and check that your anonymized web.config matches the one used to get the error? Then take a step back and ask yourself if there's perhaps something missing you wanted to know if you were a fellow worker, and add it.